# VBA Code: Substract value until it reaches ZERO

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I've been trying to run a code in VBA that has the following logical scheme:

- If "MVT Inventory" (represented by the column C) < "Tot Inventory" (represented by the column D), then show the difference ("Tot Inventory" - "MVT Inventory") on the cell located at the "Tot Inventory" column itself;
- If ("MVT Inventory" > "Tot Inventory"), then find the next "Tot Inventory" with the same letter on the column B and subtract what remains of the difference "MVT Inventory" - "Tot Inventory" until this difference reaches ZERO.

Example:

A - "MVT Inventory" = 500 and "Tot Inventory" = 1200, then "Tot Inventory" = 1200 - 500 = 700

Another A - "MVT Inventory" = 1500 and "Tot Inventory" = 400, the "Tot Inventory" = - 1100.
The difference of -1100 needs to find another row that has an A at the Name column and subtract with another "Tot Inventory" until the difference reaches ZERO. Besides that, all cells at the MVT column need to reach ZERO at the end of the program.

Here is the worksheet I'm working at:
[image]

And here is the code I've done. I'm having issues after the `Else` command on the first `If` condition. Before that the code ran okay.

```vb
Dim i, j, k As Integer
Dim dif

last_main_row = Sheets("Inventories").Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
last_name_row = Sheets("Inventories").Range("H" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

For j = 5 To last_name_row
    While Cells(j, "I") <> 0
        For i = 4 To last_main_row
            dif = Cells(i, "D") - Cells(i, "C")
            If dif >= 0 Then
                Cells(i, "D") = dif
                Cells(i, "C") = 0
            Else
                While dif < 0
                    For k = 4 To last_main_row
                        If Cells(j, "B") = Cells(k, "B") Then
                            Cells(k, "D") = Cells(k, "D") + dif
                            dif = dif + Cells(k, "D")
                        End If
                    Next
                Wend
            End If
        Next
    Wend
Next
```

Comment: Why can't you just add up all the `Tot Inventory` per `Name` and get a real total per name? Then work from that?

Comment: NOTE: A better tool for an inventory system is MSAccess. There a plenty of templates and examples that will solve most of your problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
' Try this instead
Sub testnja()

    Dim NameRow As Range
    Dim NameInvRow As Range
    Dim NameInvRowFind As Range
    
    For Each NameRow In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(8).Cells
        
        NameRow.Select
        
        If NameRow.Row > 1 Then
            If Trim(NameRow) <> "" Then
            
                For Each NameInvRow In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(2).Cells
                    If NameInvRow = NameRow Then
                                   
                        If NameInvRow.Offset(0, 2) >= NameInvRow.Offset(0, 1) Then
                            NameInvRow.Offset(0, 2) = NameInvRow.Offset(0, 2) - NameInvRow.Offset(0, 1)
                            NameInvRow.Offset(0, 1) = 0
                        Else
                            
                            For Each NameInvRowFind In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(2).Cells
                                If NameInvRowFind = NameRow And _
                                    NameInvRowFind.Row <> NameInvRow.Row Then
                                    
                                    If NameInvRowFind.Offset(0, 2) >= NameInvRow.Offset(0, 1) Then
                                        NameInvRowFind.Offset(0, 2) = NameInvRowFind.Offset(0, 2) - NameInvRow.Offset(0, 1)
                                        NameInvRow.Offset(0, 1) = 0
                                        Exit For
                                    End If
                                        
                                End If
                            Next
                        
                        End If
                    
                    End If
                Next
            
            Else
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add the diff to MVT column rather than subtract from Tot you avoid recursion should the Tot be less than the difference.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub a()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim dif As Long, sName As String
    Dim last_main_row As Long, last_name_row As Long

    With Sheets("Inventories")
        last_main_row = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        last_name_row = .Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    For i = 2 To last_main_row
        dif = Cells(i, "D") - Cells(i, "C")
        sName = Cells(i, "B")
        If dif >= 0 Then
            Cells(i, "C") = 0
            Cells(i, "D") = dif
        Else
           ' add diff onto next occurance of name
           For k = i + 1 To last_main_row
               If Cells(k, "B") = sName Then
                   Cells(k, "C") = Cells(k, "C") - dif
                   Cells(i, "C") = 0
                   Cells(i, "D") = 0
                   dif = 0
                   Exit For
               End If
            Next
            If dif <> 0 Then
                MsgBox "No record " & sName & " for diff of " & dif, vbExclamation
            End If
        End If
    Next
 
End Sub
```